# how to create enumerated element handles

Tags: javascript, element, getelementbyid

I have a lot of div's with text that I'll be animating (in the 100's)
And I need a way of creating enumerated element handles (trying to avoid an array)
like this:

```
<div id="q1"> some text </div>
<div id="q2"> some text </div>
```

...
in javascript i would like to create the element handles in a for loop  (the animation processor needs element handles)

like:

```
for( let i=0; i<numQues; i++ ) {
    let q + i = document.getElementById("q"+i)
}
```

Obviously, this doesn't work, but that is what i am trying to do, where I would then have the element handles as  q1  for <div id="q1"     q2 for <div id="q2" etc

Answer (score -1):

With this code snippet you will be able to iterate through multiple items in the DOM and animate them, I'm using classes, although, you can do whatever you want, but, I think you can get the idea.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
items.forEach(
  (item, i) =>
    setTimeout(
      () => item.classList.add('visible'),
      100 * i
    )
);
```

```css
.item {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 250ms ease-out;
}

.item.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="i1" class="item">item 1</div>
<div id="i2" class="item">item 2</div>
<div id="i3" class="item">item 3</div>
<div id="i4" class="item">item 4</div>
<div id="i5" class="item">item 5</div>
<div id="i6" class="item">item 6</div>
<div id="i7" class="item">item 7</div>
<div id="i8" class="item">item 8</div>
<div id="i9" class="item">item 9</div>
<div id="i10" class="item">item 10</div>
```

Comment: well, that won't work in my case. I using the GSAP (Greensock) library for animation, synced to a video tape with lots of animation.  I create timeline   like tl=timeline()  then the animtions will be:  tl..fromTo( q[8], .6, {color:"#04f", left:"1.5%", top:"12%", autoAlpha:0, scale:0, width:"48%", transformOrigin:"left top"}, {color:"#000", autoAlpha:1, scale:toScale}, 9.4 )   etc.   so i was wanting to create the element handles.  I mean, I can do them as an array, I guess there's no good reason not to.